# How to enable/disable Html helper on MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm starting to play around with MVC. I did the NerdDinner walkthrough and now I'm creating a simple project that displays the products in the Northwinds database. I have a details view, a create view, and an edit view. I figured out how to display a checkbox for the boolean property, "Discontinued", but I want the control to be disabled on the details view (since the edit view is used for editing). This is what I have:

```
<div class="display-label">Discontinued: <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Discontinued)%></div>
```

I'm not sure how to get to or set the enabled property of the checkbox. (I suppose I could do it using javascript, but I'm thinking there is a better way). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do `<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Discontinued, new { disabled = disabled })%>`

to pass in HtmlAttributes in the constructor.

**EDIT**
For Razor in MVC4, you would do similar to this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyValue, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: I don't think that this part : new { disabled = disabled }) works

Comment: @Misi Updated the answer to include razor, and how you would do it with MVC4